# Error at /basic_app/ Invalid block tag on line 10: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I am a beginner in HTML templates and Django.

basic_app_base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Base</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'basic_app:list' %}">School</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      {% block body_block %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

#### **school_list.html**

```
{% extends "basic_app/basic_app_base.html" %}
<!-- {% load static %} -->
{% block body_block %}
<h1>Here are the list of all the schools!</h1>
  <ol>
    {% for school in schools %}
      <h2><li><a href="{{school.id}}">{{school.name}}</a></li></h2>
    {% endfor % }
  </ol>
{% endblock %}
```

**Error:**TemplateSyntaxError at /basic_app/

Invalid block tag on line 10: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

#### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (View,TemplateView,
                                  ListView,DetailView)
from . import models
# from django.http import HttpResponse

# Template views with CBV
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name='index.html'

# List View
class SchoolListView(ListView): 
    context_object_name='schools'
    model=models.School
    template_name='basic_app/school_list.html'


# Detail View
class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name='school_detail'
    model=models.School
    template_name='basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class School(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal=models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school=models.ForeignKey(School,related_name='students',on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, re_path
# from django.conf.urls import url
from basic_app import views

app_name='basic_app'
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='list'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='detail')
]
```

I need output like the following image, when clicking on school page :
[image: output image]

Comment: please provide basic_app_base.html template

Comment: give basic_app_base.html  to find out that error

Comment: done !! please check the question again

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, and I was giving too much space after the % when closing the endfor tag.

error on **school_list.html** file
in line 8 :{% endfor % }
too much space after the % when closing the endfor tag.

solution: {% endfor %}

"After correcting this error on the line 8, it worked for me."

Answer (score 0):

Need remove extra space afrer % in `{% endfor % }`

#### after correction

```
{% extends "basic_app/basic_app_base.html" %}
<!-- {% load static %} -->
{% block body_block %}
<h1>Here are the list of all the schools!</h1>
  <ol>
    {% for school in schools %}
      <h2><li><a href="{{school.id}}">{{school.name}}</a></li></h2>
    {% endfor %} <---------------------- in this line need correction, put {% endfor %} insted of {% endfor % }
  </ol>
{% endblock %}
```